# PCIe EP device getting failed to enumerate always

Tags: linux, bios, pci-express

I have a pcie EP(Endpoint) device & host Linux PC is acting as RC(Root-Complex).
**Setup Info**: For Linkup, I turn on the host PC & then turn on EP device (as the clock is coming from host PC) & run pll-lock script for EP device & then I restart the PC(without full power-cycle).

**Issue**: Now, my EP will be enumerated sometimes only(3 out of 10) times but **once link-up**,restarting the host PC or power-cycling the EP device will result in linkup always.
Is this related to BIOS/PCIe bus syncing? What may be the cause?Any suggestions.

Comment: Someone please help on this asap..